# build aosp sample sdk addon failed due to No rule to make target `images/source.properties'

Tags: android, sdk, add-on

I have synced android 5.1.1,then I want to build sample sdk addon,but it failed with following info:

make -j8 PRODUCT-sample_addon-sdk_addon

...
make: *** No rule to make target `images/source.properties', needed by`out/host/linux-x86/obj/SDK_ADDON/platform_library_intermediates/platform_library-eng.tonywu-linux-x86-img'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

I also googled online but didn't find any clue of similar failure.

Answer (score 1):

Solution,you need to make 2 changes on top of AOSP code:

1. Create file source.properties under device/sample/sdk_addon
2. Add one line in sample_addon.mk:

`PRODUCT_SDK_ADDON_SYS_IMG_SOURCE_PROP := $(LOCAL_PATH)/source.properties`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking on how to build sample add-on on the latest AOSP source checkout (Android 12L), here is the guide:

***This error is immortal. This is 2022, Android has jumped to 12 but it still hails.***

You solve this and another one greets you:

**FAILED: ninja: 'out/target/common/docs/platform_library-timestamp', needed by 'out/host/linux-x86/sdk_addon/platform_library-eng.-linux-x86.zip', missing and no known rule to make it**

Apparently, the task "javadoc" defined in device/sample/frameworks/PlatformLibrary/Android.bp doesn't execute (or succeeds, don't know, couldn't figure it out), causing this dependency to be pending.

To solve this, you need to comment out the below line in device/sample/products/sample_addon.mk
PRODUCT_SDK_ADDON_DOC_MODULES := platform_library

Hope this helps someone stuck!

Hail ANDROID!

Comment: Nice,it works. I suspect Google has forgotten about this feature.